# How to watch any window movements with xlib?

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

How do I track move event for all the windows? 
Like if user moves window "Pluma" my daemon would receive window name and new coordinates.

```
if(XCheckMaskEvent(display, -1, &event))
    {
        if(event.type == ConfigureNotify)
        {
            moved += event.xmotion.x + event.xmotion.y;
            //qDebug << moved;
        }
    }
```

I tried tracking it like this, but it does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need t select `SubstructureNotify` mask on the root window first:

```
XSelectInput(display, XDefaultRootWindow(display), SubstructureNotifyMask );
```

This way you are telling X server "I'm interested in root window childrens move/resize/delete/create events"